# Matching a search with a regular expression and four lines of context

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

For example, I have this kind of code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Order
 *
 * The WooCommerce order class handles order data.
 *
 * @class       WC_Order
 * @version     1.6.4
 * @package     WooCommerce/Classes
 * @category    Class
 * @author      WooThemes
 */
class WC_Order {

    /** @public int Order (post) ID */
    public $id;

    /** @public string Order status. */
    public $status;

    /** @public string Order date (placed). */
    public $order_date;

    /** @public string Order date (paid). */
    public $modified_date;

    /** @public string Note added by the customer. */
    public $customer_note;

    /** @public array Order (post) meta/custom fields. */
    public $order_custom_fields;

        global $wpdb, $woocommerce;

        if ( empty( $type ) )
            $type = array( 'line_item' );

        if ( ! is_array( $type ) )
            $type = array( $type );

        $items = $this->get_items( $type );

        $count = 0;

        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            if ( ! empty( $item['qty'] ) )
                $count += $item['qty'];
            else
                $count ++;
        }

        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_item_count', $count, $type, $this );
    }

    /**
     * Return an array of fees within this order.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_fees() {
        return $this->get_items( 'fee' );
    }

    /**
     * Return an array of taxes within this order.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function get_taxes() {
        return $this->get_items( 'tax' );
    }

    /**
     * Get taxes, merged by code, formatted ready for output.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function get_tax_totals() {
        $taxes      = $this->get_items( 'tax' );
        $tax_totals = array();

        foreach ( $taxes as $key => $tax ) {

            $code = $tax[ 'name' ];

            if ( ! isset( $tax_totals[ $code ] ) ) {
                $tax_totals[ $code ] = new stdClass();
                $tax_totals[ $code ]->amount = 0;
            }

            $tax_totals[ $code ]->is_compound       = $tax[ 'compound' ];
            $tax_totals[ $code ]->label             = isset( $tax[ 'label' ] ) ? $tax[ 'label' ] : $tax[ 'name' ];
            $tax_totals[ $code ]->amount           += $tax[ 'tax_amount' ] + $tax[ 'shipping_tax_amount' ];
            $tax_totals[ $code ]->formatted_amount  = woocommerce_price( $tax_totals[ $code ]->amount );
        }

        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_tax_totals', $tax_totals, $this );
    }

    /**
     * has_meta function for order items.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return array of meta data
     */
    public function has_meta( $order_item_id ) {
        global $wpdb;

        return $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_key, meta_value, meta_id, order_item_id
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE order_item_id = %d
            ORDER BY meta_key,meta_id", absint( $order_item_id ) ), ARRAY_A );
    }

    /**
     * Get order item meta.
     *
     * @access public
     * @param mixed $item_id
     * @param string $key (default: '')
     * @param bool $single (default: false)
     * @return void
     */
    public function get_item_meta( $order_item_id, $key = '', $single = false ) {
        return get_metadata( 'order_item', $order_item_id, $key, $single );
}
```

I want to match all Wordpress hooks: "do_action" and "apply_filters" with three options:
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_tax_totals', $tax_totals, $this ), file, line number

An example of what i'm trying to do can be seen here:
http://etivite.com/api-hooks/buddypress/trigger/apply_filters/bp_get_total_mention_count_for_user/

http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/activated_plugin?version=3.6&file=wp-admin/includes/plugin.php

I did try to pull something out but with no success:

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/iphorm-form-builder';
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $filename) {
    if (substr($filename, -3) == 'php') {
        $file = file($filename);
        if ($file !== false) {
            $matches1 = preg_grep( '/do_action\((.+)\);/', $file);
            $matches2 = preg_grep( '/apply_filters\((.+)\);/', $file );
            $arr = array_filter(array_merge($matches1, $matches2));
            $out = '';
            echo "found in $filename:";
            echo "<pre>";
            foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                $out .= $file[$key-2];
                $out .= $file[$key-1];
                $out .= $file[$key];
                $out .= $file[$key+1];
                $out .= $file[$key+2];
            }
            echo htmlentities($out);
            echo "</pre>";
        } else {
            echo "failed reading to array";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this thread for some advice on getting more attention for old questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: What is the expected output for the example code you have given?

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. The terminology you need is "context". You want a line matched, with 4 lines of *context*.

Comment: WTF?? `global $wpdb, $woocommerce;` in a class

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem welcome to wordpress. Check your sanity at the door.

Comment: @JoeFrambach: No need, I'm gone... I can't _believe_ this is actually being used... Another good example of why PHP's rep isn't exactly helped by Wp or drupal...

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very simply by taking advantage of built-in shell commands.

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/iphorm-form-builder';
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $filename) {
    if (substr($filename, -3) == 'php') {
        $context = shell_exec('grep -H -n -C4 do_action ' . escapeshellarg($filename));
        if (!empty($context)) {
            echo "found in $filename:";
            echo "<pre>";
            echo htmlentities($context);
            echo "</pre>";
        } else {
            echo "failed reading to array";
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant documentation:

[php shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

> Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

[php escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

> Escape a string to be used as a shell argument

[bash grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)

> ```
>    Grep  searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are
>    named, or the file name - is given) for lines containing a match to the
>    given PATTERN.  By default, grep prints the matching lines.
>
>    -C NUM, --context=NUM
>       Print  NUM lines of output context.  Places a line containing --
>       between contiguous groups of matches.
>
>    -H, --with-filename
>       Print the filename for each match.
>
>    -n, --line-number
>       Prefix each line of output with the line number within its input
>       file.
> ```

**Edit**

Depending on how many directories and files you have in your project, it may not be performant. You're basically creating a new process in a new shell for each file. That's not great. If you'd rather get a big dump of data and parse it out later, do this instead:

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/iphorm-form-builder';
$grep = shell_exec('grep --include=*.php -RHn -C4 do_action ' . escapeshellarg($path));
$matches = explode("\n--\n", $grep);
if (empty($matches)) {
    echo "failed reading to array";
}
else {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        echo "<pre>";
        echo htmlentities($match);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Gee, this is sweet indeed, am building a plugin out of it right now :) The content directory can be anywhere, if used in WP context, this is more bulletproof: `$path = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins/plugin-name';`

Comment: Hi Joe,
Sorry for the delay didn't was near a computer a long time :-) Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through file data line by line. Just read the data in a variable and apply regex:

```
$data = file_get_contents( $filename );
if (preg_match_all(
      '~((?:[^\n]*\n){0,4}) *do_action\s*\(\s*([^)]+)\s*\)\s*;[^\n]*\n((?:[^\n]*\n){0,4})~',
       $data, $arr)) {
   // match found, now dump the results
   // $arr[1] will print 4 lines before the match
   // $arr[2] will print function arguments for do_action
   // $arr[3] will print 4 lines after the match
   print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: @JoeFrambach: Yes indeed `$arr[3] will print 4 lines after the match` and you are correct about first 4 lines from the file, check the edit now.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done by regular expressions alone given the limitations of PHP's regular expression engine.  Specifically, and it came as a surprise to me, you can not have variable length look behinds.

The reason you need look behinds is if you had the occurrence of **do_action** or **apply_filters** on consecutive lines, then the first match will prevent the second match if you had no look aheads, and even if you use look aheads, there is no way to get the previous two rows of the second match without the look behinds.  Not to mention I don't even know if you can even include the contents of a look around assertion in the result.

This solution creates a regular expression to find the lines in which the function occurs, and then uses two more regexes to find the lines before and after.  I took care to watch out for the start and end of file when designing the regexes.

```
$offset = 0;
while (preg_match('/^.*?(?:apply_filters|do_action)\s*\(.+?\)\s*;.*(?:\n\r|\n|\r|$)/m', $file, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset))
{
    $index = $match[0][1];
    $offset = $index + strlen($match[0][0]);
    $hasBefore = preg_match('/(?:.*(?:\n\r|\n|\r).*$)|[^\n\r].*$/', 
        substr($file, 0, $index), $beforeMatch);
    $hasAfter = preg_match('/^(?:.*(?:\n\r|\n|\r|$)){0,2}/', 
        substr($file, $offset), $afterMatch);

    if ($hasBefore) print_r($beforeMatch);
    print_r($match[0][0]);
    if ($hasAfter) print_r($afterMatch);
}
```

### [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wa7-ygg)

This only displays two lines before and two lines after.  You can use repetition if you want more, but it appears to me from the attempted solution that this was what the o.p. really wanted.